# Resetting network settings in Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04, network-manager

In my Ubuntu 13.04 I was messing around with the network connections without creating backups. Now I have done something to the network after which the Network Manager isn't showing up at top right. I use `ppp` and when I run the command `sudo pppoeconf` it runs perfectly but it doesn’t connect to the Internet. To connect, I opened another account in Ubuntu and I can connect easily through that account. I used these commands in my older account as far as I recall:

```
airodump-ng wlan0
airodump-ng eth0
```

Is there any way to reset the network configuration to the initial installation state?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I struggled with a similar problem, and I stumbled on [this](http://solancer.blogspot.ro/2011/10/network-icon-disappeared-in-ubuntu-1110.html). It solved my problem pretty fast.

I first went to `/etc/NetworkManager/` where I found the file `NetworkManager.conf`, then disabled Network Manager with this command:

```
sudo service network-manager stop
```

Then I opened `NetworkManager.conf` with the nano text editor:

```
sudo nano NetworkManager.conf
```

and changed `ifupdown managed=false` to `ifupdown managed=true`

then restarted the Network manager using this:

```
sudo service network-manager start
```

And that's it!